# Replacing single quote characters in a column in Amazon Redshift

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

I have some data in a table in the following format in `Amazon Redshift`:

```
Column1    Column2
'a'          'b'
```

I'd like to remove the single quote characters from this table and get the data as follows:

```
Column1    Column2
a            b
```

I would have thought the `Replace` function would do the trick, so I wrote the following query:

```
select replace(column1,''',''),
       replace(column2,''','')
from table
```

But this doesn't work and gives me `Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: unterminated quoted string at or near "''','')`. I tried to escape the single quote character by `\` but even that didn't work.

I also tried using the following query:

```
select replace(column1,"'",''),
           replace(column2,"'",'')
    from table
```

But it gave me the error `[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "'" does not exist in <tablename>`

So how do I remove these single characters from my data?

Any help would be much appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: How did the quotes get in there in the first place? That's the real problem you need to solve.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Amazon Redshift? Please remove the incorrect tag.

Comment: You can add postgresql tag, mysql is not related to this question. Is it?

Comment: @Patthebug Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Answer (score 8):

```
select replace(column1,chr(39),''),
       replace(column2,chr(39),'')
from table
```

The CHR function returns the character that matches the ASCII code point value specified by of the input parameter. 
If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Answer (score 5):

With MySQL you have two ways of quoting, so you need to switch:

```
REPLACE(column1, "'", "")
```

You can't use the same character for both delimiting and content without escaping:

```
REPLACE(column1, '\'', '')
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in my original question, having double quotes also doesn't work. It gives me the error `[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "'" does not exist in <tablename>`

Comment: What about the second option? If you're using `ANSI_QUOTES` the first is out but that's not the default for MySQL.

Comment: I can confirm that the second option works correctly in Amazon Redshift: `select replace(column1, '\'', ''), replace(column2, '\'', '') from table;`

Comment: replace(column1,chr(39),'') also works on Athena, on which you can't use the double quotes (because they are used to enclose column names and reserved keywords, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-databases-columns-names.html#tables-databases-columns-names-reserved-words)